# GIT - Commit em outra branch

Tags: git, commit, merge, branch

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que possui duas branchs (master e dev).

Comecei a implantação de uma nova feature no sistema mas, na metade do caminho, percebi que estava fazendo as alterações na master, ao invés da dev.

Existe uma forma de eu terminar o código e fazer o commit direto na branch de dev e deixar a master como era antes de eu começar a codar?

Ou o jeito vai ser:

Copiar tudo que eu fiz;
Deletar o projeto;
Baixar de novo do repositório;
Ir para a branch dev;
colar tudo que eu fiz.

Obrigado a quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Você já fez algum commit dessas novas alterações na master??

Comment: @viana ainda não

Comment: Obviamente você pode terminar de codificar e criar uma nova branch com essas alteraçãoes: Ex: git checkout -b feature/2 ... ai você 'comitta' lá dentro. Depois só fazer merge com dev. É uma saida.

Comment: Se você não adicionou nem comitou nem deu nenhum push na master ainda, ta muito simples resolver. Faz isso que estou fazendo. Pode até fazer antes de terminar de codificar. Já vai criar uma branch novo e migrar automático. Mas fique atento ao número da feature. Tente colocar alguma coisa que não exista ainda.

Comment: @viana então, sendo assim, eu criei uma branch nova aqui, com outro nome e tudo mas a minha master ainda está com as alterações, eu posso simplesmente desfazer as alterações?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Termine o que tiver para terminar e faça o commit normalmente.
Depois, certifique-se de que está na master utilizando `git checkout master` e use `git log`  para visualizar todos os commits que você fez.
Verifique quais são os que deseja mudar, e os identifique pelo começo de seu hash, por exemplo:

```
commit 53d51100b6bbcd7c27ae19d8ba5765f76afb9184 (HEAD -> master)
```

é um commit identificável pelo começo `53d5`.

Em seguida, vá para o branch com

```
git checkout dev
```

E utilize o `cherry-pick` para trazer os commits que você fez na master:

```
git cherry-pick hash1 hash2 hash3...
```

Onde as hashes são os identificadores que mencionei acima.

Após essa etapa, a branch deverá conter os commits que você fez na master, e a master também.

Para remover da master os commits, e deixá-la no estado inicial, identifique o primeiro commit que deixa da forma que você quer e rode:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard hash
```

Onde hash é o identificador do commit em que deseja deixar a master.

Comment: É cara, eu fui afobado aqui e mandei um reset --hard na master pelo visual studio e acabei perdendo as coisas que eu tinha feito, agora vou ter que refazer tudo de novo. mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Caso tu ainda não comitou suas alterações, tu pode usar o git stash.

Primeiro tu da um `git stash`, então tudo que tu alterou ficará salvo na memória, e depois tu muda para a branch correta e da um `git stash apply` que irá aplicar as alterações na branch em que tu estiver.